# Странный казус в работе getline()

Tags: c++, c++11

```
Написал вот такой код:

#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string figure;
        int N;
        cin >> N;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            getline(cin, figure);
            if(figure[0] == 'T') count+= 4;
            if(figure[0] == 'I') count += 20;
            if(figure[0] == 'D') count += 12;
            if(figure[0] == 'O') count += 8;
            if(figure[0] == 'C') count += 6;
        }

        cout << count;
    }
```

При i = 0 getline не работает, ввод запрашивает на 1 раз меньше чем требуется.
В чём проблема работы getline() ?

Comment: Первая `getline()` (при `i == 0`) читает остаток строки (вероятно пустой), оставшийся  во входном потоке после `cin >> N;`

Answer (score 2):

После

```
cin >> N;
```

в буфере ввода остаются `<CR><LF>` которые считываются первым вызовом

```
getline(cin, figure);
```

интерперетируясь как пустая строка. Выход пропустить эти символы, вызвав после

```
cin >> N;
```

```
cin.ignore();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну а зачем считывать строку, если вам нужен только ее первый символ?
Лучше считывать только один символ, а всю остальную строку инорировать. Вот аналогичный код:

```
char c;
int N, count = 0;
cin >> N;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cin >> c;       
    switch (c)
    {
    case 'T':  count += 4; break;
    case 'I':  count += 20; break;
    case 'D':  count += 12; break;
    case 'O':  count += 8; break;
    case 'C':  count += 6; break;       
    }   
    // игнорируем всю остальную строку
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
}
cout << count;
```