# При сравнении двух одинаковых строк выдает False

Tags: c++

Пишу программу палиндром. Слова получаются одинаковыми, но при сравнении выдает false

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//шалаш 

int main() {
    std::string one;
    std::string second;

    std::getline(std::cin,one);

    for (int i = one.length(); i >= 0;i-- ) {

        second += one[i];

    }

    std::cout <<  "ONE: " << one  << "\n";
    std::cout << "SECOND: " << second << "\n";
    if (one == second) {
        std::cout << "ok";
    }
}
```

Вопрос: почему не сравниваются две одинаковые строки?(регистры одинаковые)

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002211/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-getline) Возможно, у Вас аналогичная проблема.

Comment: Потому что строки у вас неодинаковые, от слова совсем, даже по длине. Их содержимое следует просматривать в отладчике, а не печатать.

Comment: `one.length()` -> `one.length() - 1`